# How to make the Picture Live Tile show more pictures?

Tags: windows-8, live-tiles

I seem to have quite the opposite problem than other users do: my picture live tile keeps showing the same seven or eight pictures, although there are hundreds in the library.

Can I affect this? I like the function, but it is frustrating to see the same seven pictures all over again. Is there any way I can force it to have more variety?

Answer (score 0):

It displays 5 pictures from the 50 most recent pictures in your photo library.

There is no way to change it without modification, which is why i'm looking around for some program or tweak that will force the live tile to show more then 5 images at once.

Answer (score 0):

Use your desktop live tile as your picture viewer by selecting your pictures folder (or any other folder with pictures in it) as your desktop background in Personalize